# Heroku Rails Page Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, gemfile

I'm trying to deploy a sample rails app on heroku. After creating a very basic app, adding a git repository, committing everything and "heroku create", I push it up to heroku. No errors at all in terminal, but when I open the browser with the correct address, I get the following:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

I've searched for three hours and used the heroku tutorial on how to deploy the app but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'json'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'railties', '4.0.0.beta1'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  #gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  #gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I've repeated the steps above several times, didn't work. Thanks!

Edit: added heroku console logs:

```
2013-04-13T14:15:14.800540+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.801066+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.801066+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.801375+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-13 14:15:14] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-04-13T14:15:14.801542+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-13 14:15:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-04-13T14:15:14.801066+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.800540+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0.beta1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44478
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 178.25.122.239 at 2013-04-13 14:02:08 +0000
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.822878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 178.25.122.239 at 2013-04-13 14:04:08 +0000
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823433+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823657+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.823871+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 178.25.122.239 at 2013-04-13 14:04:09 +0000
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bu
ndle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-04-13T14:15:14.824503+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:15:14.516222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-13T14:15:16.056837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: To disable this message remove the `whitelist_attributes` option from your
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Model based mass assignment security has been extracted
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: out of Rails into a gem. Please use the new recommended protection model for
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: params or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use the old one.
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: `config/application.rb` file and any `mass_assignment_sanitizer` options
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment for more information.
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-13T14:16:05.609544+00:00 app[web.1]: from your `config/environments/*.rb` files.
2013-04-13T14:16:05.730223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=mighty-depths-7233.herokuapp.com fwd="178.25.122.239" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=209ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-04-13T14:16:05.980431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mighty-depths-7233.herokuapp.com fwd="178.25.122.239" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=728
```

Comment: Please run `heroku logs` and add the output to your question.

Comment: What do your routes look like? It appears rails doesn't have a route for /

Comment: Oh, that seems to be right. I did run heroku rake routes and it says "You don't have any routes defined!". I'm new to rails, shouldn't the rails standard welcome page open when the projekt has been created? How can I set that / route? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all there's a good guide [on routing in Rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Lets say you have an `Article` model in your app and an articles controller, you have to define the routes for this resource under config/routes.rb. Rails allows you to add routes for `index, show new, create, edit, update` and `destroy` in one line:

```
resources :articles
```

This will map to the following:

```
GET     /articles           index   display a list of all articles
GET     /articles/new       new     return an HTML form for creating a new article
POST    /articles           create  create a new article
GET     /articles/:id       show    display a specific article
GET     /articles/:id/edit  edit    return an HTML form for editing a article
PUT     /articles/:id       update  update a specific article
DELETE  /articles/:id       destroy delete a specific article
```

However to make sure that the homepage routes to one of these actions you need to define `root` under config/routes.rb

```
root to: "articles#index"
```

Then commit and push it to heroku again.

Comment: See my answer for the root ;) cause for this user.

Comment: Continuing with version 4 may uncover more of these confusing changes.  As a newbie you may wish to stick with rails 3+ to avoid frustration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that. I'm having a hard time telling my system not to use rails 4 though...

Answer (score 1):

I  notice that you're trying (probably unintentionally) to use an 'edge' version of rails (4+).

I would stick with a 3.x version for now and that's what the tutorial is probably assuming.

You can use this to create an app with a specific version (3.2 in this case)

```
rails _3.2_ new myapp
```

If you don't have that version of rails on your system you may need to install it, e.g.

```
gem install -v=3.2 rails
```

or, if that fails,

```
sudo gem install rails -v3.2
```

The above is why, when you follow the current Heroku instructions it assumes rails 3 and that version does do that default root path and the public/index.html file

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I had a demo project before running rails 3 and I think it mapped the route automatically to the rails welcome page so I didn't think this would the problem... But now i know, thanks! :)